# spark scala dataframe timestamp conversion sorting?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv of the form:

```
t,value
2012-01-12 12:30:00,4
2012-01-12 12:45:00,3
2012-01-12 12:00:00,12
2012-01-12 12:15:00,13
2012-01-12 13:00:00,7
```

I convert that into dataframe using [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv]). (so `t` is in `String` type and `value` is in Integer type). What's the appropriate spark scala way so the output is sorted by time?

I was thinking to convert `t` to certain type which can allow dataframe `sortBy`. But I am not familiar which timestamp type allow dataframe sorting by time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the format you can either cast to timestamp to

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType

df.select($"t".cast(TimestampType)) // or df.select($"t".cast("timestamp"))
```

to get proper date time or use `unix_timestamp` (Spark 1.5+, in Spark < 1.5 you can use a Hive UDF of the same name) function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp

df.select(unix_timestamp($"t"))
```

to get a numerical representation (Unix timestamp in **seconds**).

On a side note there is no reason you couldn't `orderBy($"t")` directly. Lexicographic order should work just fine here.

Comment: Thanks @zero323, the unix_timestamp maps it to seconds really help for subsequent sorting!

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to @zero323, if you are writing pure SQL you can use the CAST   operator as follows:

```
df.registerTempTable("myTable")    
sqlContext.sql("SELECT CAST(t as timestamp) FROM myTable")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cast using 'df.select', then you might get only the column specified.
To change the type of the column specified, & retain other columns, apply 'df.withColumn' and pass the original column name.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df1 = df.withColumn("t",col("t").cast(TimestampType))

df1.printSchema
root
 |-- t: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- value: integer (nullable = true)
```

Only the datatype of the column name "t" is changed.
Rest is retained.